# Groff text output processing issues

Tags: text, text-processing, groff

I need to format documents with the groff -mm macros and need help on some issues:
[image: image showing issues]

============
You can see it is putting some blank lines at the top and a page number. I need it to run one continuous column starting at the first line of the file.
It is using ansi escape codes, i need it to strictly use ascii text characters.
I also want no default indentation and the page width needs to be 80 chars wide as i am sending it to a text file not a printer.

Answer (score 4):

You can reformat the page with `.PGFORM <line length> <page length> <page offset> <line break>`. `.PGNH` skips the header printing on the first page.

```
.PGFORM 80 0 0 1
.PGNH
ConImp [-a] [-t] [n<name>] [m<time>] [e<editor>]
  -a = non-ANSI terminal
  -t = use test port
  -n = force user name
  -m = maximum play time
  -e<editor> = allow external editor

-a:
  If your terminal is not ANSI compatible use this to prevent ANSI codes being sent

-t:
  Use the testing port

-n<name>:
  Force the username to this user, used in BBS doors

-m<time>:
  Set maximim play time

-e<editor>:
  Set the external editor, if any. For example to use VI editor
```

The text above is only guessed ;-)

I guess that the escape characters are added by the tty output device (`-T ascii`) which is grotty. grotty allows you to disable color and escape sequences by the -c option. This flag should be propergated to grotty if you call `groff -c ...` .

### Edit

with the following call you can switch off the hidden call to grotty with -Z and pipe the output to an explicit call of grotty with the -c flag.

```
groff  -mm -Tascii conimp.mm -Z|grotty -c
```